# Characters displaying issues into Excel / text file?

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8, preg-replace

When i open the excel file exported for many data, some Characters appear like : `�` although i set the encoding to `utf-8` and in the script used to export data i use the function below: `preg_replace('/[\s]+/',' ',@$tring);` and `$string="le secteur public à réagir";` in the excel file, $string appears like this : `le secteur public � réagir`, why 'é' is converted right but 'à' no?the utf-8 is put right.

Thank you.

Comment: Would you please post the script to export the data (it can tend to get converted to ASCII text with PHP)?  Also, if you are opening the general utf-8 formatted information in Excel but from text it doesn't mean Excel understands that it does it's own conversion on open. A code sample would help greatly.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `echo $string` before using `preg_replace('/[\s]+/',' ',@$tring);`?

This code runs properly when using Chrome, its output is `le secteur public à réagir`.

When I run this code in command line, its output is `le secteur public α rΘagir`.

So, I think the problem here is not `preg_replace('/[\s]+/',' ',@$tring);`

Comment: Maybe the charset of the excel file.

Comment: How to set it?for utf8 encoding?

Comment: How i can tell excel to set the utf8 encoding for all special characters and type of text??

Comment: Kindly, when i eliminate the preg_replace('/[\s]+/',' ',@$tring); then the output is appeared correctly...but its necessary to do this for some special characters.

Answer (score 0):

Your regex is missing the `u` (utf-8) modifier:

```
preg_replace('/[\s]+/u',' ',@$tring);
                     ^
```